# join the previous month record where id and current date in another table -SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables to be joined. I'm trying to join the current month with last month's record of each ID. I only want to join the previous date and value from Table B. What is the optimal way to join using teradata?

Table A

| ID | Date A | Utility |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 202008 | $ 200 |
| 222 | 202007 | $ 300 |

Table B

| ID | Date B | Saving |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 202008 | $200 |
| 111 | 202007 | $120 |
| 222 | 202007 | $900 |
| 222 | 202006 | $800 |

**Expected table:**
Table C

| ID | Date A | Utility | Date B | Saving |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 202008 | $ 200 | 202007 | $120 |
| 222 | 202007 | $ 300 | 202006 | $800 |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @forpas oh ok, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with *Postgres*.

```
select *
from   t join t2 on t2.id = t.id  and datediff(month, date_b, date_a) = 1
```

| ID | Date_A | Utility | ID | Date_B | Saving |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2020-08-01 | 200 | 111 | 2020-07-01 | 120 |
| 222 | 2020-07-01 | 300 | 222 | 2020-06-01 | 800 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oPn1rDWo?hide=24)

Comment: thanks for the solution, alternatively do you know how to solve using teradata?

Comment: @Jason it looks like you can substract dates in teradata. Check out the documentation: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Functions-Operators-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2017/DateTime-and-Interval-Functions-and-Expressions/Arithmetic-Operators-and-ANSI-DateTime-and-Interval-Data-Types/Examples/Example-Calculating-the-Difference-in-Days-Between-DATE-Values